# LocationPoller and multiple broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, commonsware-cwac

I am using cwac-Location Poller (from [here](https://github.com/alexbirkett/cwac-locpoll)) to constantly poll user location and display location based notifications. This all is working fine but now I am trying to attach another `BroadcastReceiver` so that if my application is in foreground, instead of displaying notification animate the google map to current user location. But for some reason I can't get it working.

`onCreate()` method of `MapActivity` I have following code to start poller:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   .....

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationPoller.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    LocationPollerParameter parameter = new LocationPollerParameter(bundle);
    parameter.setIntentToBroadcastOnCompletion(new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class));
    parameter.setProviders(new String[] {LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER});
    parameter.setTimeout(60000);
    i.putExtras(bundle);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), PERIOD, pendingIntent);                                 
}
```

in `onResume()` method I am registering another receiver using `registerReceiver()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPollerParameter.INTENT_TO_BROADCAST_ON_COMPLETION_KEY);
    intentFilter.setPriority(1);
    registerReceiver(locationReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

Where locationReceiver looks like:

```
private BroadcastReceiver locationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {      
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "mapActivity called");
        abortBroadcast();
    }
};
```

And in order to send ordered broadcast to multiple receiver I have modified `LocationPollerService` to use `sendOrderedBroadcast` instead of `sendBroadcast`

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      handler.removeCallbacks(onTimeout);
      Intent toBroadcast = createIntentToBroadcastOnCompletion();

      toBroadcast.putExtra(LocationPollerResult.LOCATION_KEY, location);        
      sendOrderedBroadcast(toBroadcast, null);
      quit();
}
```

Now the problem is my dynamically registered receiver never get called but the one mentioned in AndroidManifest.xml does:

```
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.LocationReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPoller" />
    <service android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPollerService" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in a disconnect between the `IntentFilter` you create in Java and your `createIntentToBroadcastOnCompletion()` implementation, which you did not include in your question. Your `IntentFilter` is expecting a broadcast with a certain action string -- the `Intent` you are creating in `createIntentToBroadcastOnCompletion()` apparently does not include this action string.

BTW, with respect to "And in order to send broadcast to multiple receiver", `sendBroadcast()` is perfectly capable of sending broadcasts to multiple receivers.

Comment: following is what i have in createIntentToBroadcastOnCompletion() { return new Intent(locationPollerParameter.getIntentToBroadcastOnCompletion()); } where getIntentToBroadcastOnCompletion() return exactly the same string which is "com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.EXTRA_INTENT"

Comment: @Waqas: Then `"com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.EXTRA_INTENT"` is not the same as `com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPollerParameter.INTENT_TO_BROADCAST_ON_COMPLETION_KEY`.

Comment: thanks for your quick replies- com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPollerParameter.INTENT_TO_BROADCAST_ON_COM‌​PLETION_KEY is a static string which has value com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.EXTRA_INTENT"

Comment: @Waqas: Here is a sample project using ordered broadcasts: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Ordered -- you will need to determine where what you are doing for your broadcasts differs from what is in this sample.

Comment: thanks! you were right regarding IntentFilter- the action value was not the same